# AWS S3 / EC2: Downloading file with file-saver giving CORS error

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cors

I am using AWS S3 to host my website and set my bucket with the follow CORS settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

When I try to download a file saved on my EC2 instance with the Javascript Library File-Saver, I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'EC2-Instance' from origin 'S3-Bucket' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The line that is causing the error from File-Saver is:

```
function d(a) {
    var b = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return b.open("HEAD", a, !1), b.send(), 200 <= b.status && 299 >= b.status;  <-- This line
}
```

When I simulate the request in curl with verbose on, I get the following info:

```
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
< Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
```

Any idea why I am still getting this error?

EDIT:

I tried the following request to see header details:

```
curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: S3 Bucket" --head -IXHEAD EC2_Instance
```

And am getting the following info without CORS info for some reason:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.8
Date: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 04:38:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 6950
Last-Modified: Sat, 23 Feb 2019 22:35:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5c71ca95-1b26"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Cache-Control: private
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? (You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker it is giving me a 200 OK

Comment: Try in a different browser and try force-reloading to clear your browser cache.

Comment: @sideshowbarker that still didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 not send the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header if the wildcard * like there:

```
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
```

Force s3 to send AllowedOrigin header and your content be loaded from any site, try this:

```
<AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
```

i think one will work ..!

Comment: ohhh okay..can you share screen shot of details of header ? from browser console network console

Comment: Sure I will grab that. Do you know if the origin should be my s3 bucket or EC2 instance?

Comment: if sending request from ec2 it will be ec2...from where you send request will be orign

Comment: Okay thats what I thought. The line of code giving the error is on the S3 bucket. In my above edit, when I make my S3 bucket the origin I do not see my configured CORS data. When I switch them and make EC2 the origin, I do see my configured CORS data

Comment: What exactly does that tell me? Sorry if that is a dumb question

Comment: you have to manage origin and header during uploading .https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html